# is soldering necessary for a robotics and electronics hobbyist?

Tags: soldering, robotics

I know it is VERY common but I am worried about the exposure. I do understand it is minimal if an extraction           device is used to get rid of the gasses and if a lead-free solder is used but I still have worries. I was wondering if it is essential since  I am very interested in robotics and electronics.

Comment: Your robot might trample you... There's a risk in everything. Having said that, you can just order stuff pre-fabbed as much as possible. Also use FPGAs, FPAAs etc.

Comment: This is really an irrational worry. Most processed food you buy at the grocery store is way worse for you than some occasional solder fumes.

Comment: Exposure to what? You don't say.

Comment: Ship your parts and a pile of lovely cash to me, I'll solder them and send back the soldered parts, keeping the pile of lovely cash, you'll never have to touch a soldering iron or question your irrational fears.

Answer (score 4):

No soldering is not required.

Robotics and electronics is a huge area. I know people that haven't touched an soldering iron in years because their job does not require them to do so because the field of robotics and electronics is so large.

However, depending on what your interests are and what your current level is, you may have to get your hands dirty and get into the low level stuff, such as soldering. If this is of no interest to you, then you are looking at paying someone else to make custom cables and any other assembly work you require. If time and money are of no concern to you, pay someone else to do it. Problem solved.

Though, in my opinion, learn to solder. Read up on whatever it is that is worrying you, and read about proper techniques and tools to ease yourself. It's a basic skill in this field, and you are only robbing yourself of the basic skill by avoiding it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not essential if you don't get down to actually building your own circuits but instead assemble purchased components.  If you are really interested in the details of robotics and electronics, then soldering probably can't be completely avoided.  Having said that, the dangers of soldering are not that high.  The temperatures used in normal soldering are not high enough to vaporize the metals used such as lead, tin and copper so metallic fumes are not a problem. Of course lead free solders will eliminate any exposure to lead. The biggest problem is the fumes and skin contact with the rosins used in most soldering operations. These rosins can cause a variety of medical conditions.  However, if you only solder occasionally and in a well ventilated area, the risks are minimal. If you google "solder safety", a lot of useful information will become available which you can study and decide for yourself whether you want to be involved with soldering.

Comment: could i for example.. build a line following robot but just avoid soldering the prototyped circuit or would there be some technical problem if i avoid soldering? I haven't done any project yet so i don't know

Comment: You can leave circuits on solderless breadboard, but then it's vulnerable to vibration and loose connections. If you have a PCB it has to be soldered.

Comment: @Petrarca there really isn't a big harm in soldering occasionally.
You can use a fume extractor if you're really worried, but a PC-fan is fine.

Comment: But you can use parts that have headers pre-soldered and use solderless breadboards and use those "jumper wires". You could even twist wires together and use heatshrink tubing.

But soldering will make your life easier, not shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You will occasionally break some wires here and there that's for sure. Sometime the wires and sockets get detached (unintentionally) from the main PCB and will require little soldering. You would not want to run to a technician to get it soldered right???... and that too when you already know what is broken.

Even though you may not require soldering in the beginning but you will eventually need to get yourself familiarize with the basics of soldering. IT WILL BE REQUIRED.